# How can I run code in parallel for a simple frame limiter in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, game-development

I wish to run code in parallel to make a consistent game speed regardless of framerate or computer hardware for my game.

A hypothetical Example would be -

```
public class Example extends JPanel
 {

 static boolean CalculationsCompleted;

 public static boolean render(int FREQ)
 {
     boolean render = false;

     if(CalculationsCompleted){
         render = true;
     }

     return render;
     //repeat every FREQ milliseconds
 }

 public static void Calculations()
 {
   while(true){
     CalculationsCompleted = false;

     //Do all the Calculations
     .
     .
     .
     //Calculations are finished

     CalculationsCompleted = true;
   }
 }

 public static void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
     if(render(1)){
          //update screen based on calculations
     }
     
     repaint();
 }
}
```

And all methods would be running simultaniously, using eachothers' feedback to result in the desired outcome

I've tried using a timer inbetween renders, however it did not fix this issue.

I'm just looking for someone to help or inform me of a way to do this properly.
I'm using JFrame and JPanel in case that affects anything.

If you can help me, please do so if you can, otherwise,

```
Have a nice day,
~ RedArtist
```

Comment: A really good place to start is the official Java tutorial, specifically the section on concurrency linked below which will guide you through the process of running several things in parallel to work the way you want: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: A simple way to 'make a consistent game speed regardless of framerate or computer hardware' is to ensure that the front-end display is completely separated from the back-end game engine/calculations. This is often done by having the front end read from the back end and display whatever the current state of the back-end is, then you don't have to try and sync the graphics to anything, it will always be the latest. As for making it the same on all hardware, that's a bigger issue, but you can build in pauses if necessary to slow down faster machines to match what older machines can do.